# Replace first or last character is * with % SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have string:

```
*rg*niza*io*
```

I want to replace % in the first and last character of the string. Desired out put is:

```
%rg*niza*io%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to replace only `*` with `%` from first and last positions. Then,

**Query**

```
SELECT CASE
        WHEN LEFT([string_column], 1) = '*' AND  RIGHT([string_column], 1) = '*' 
        THEN '%' + SUBSTRING([string_column], 2, LEN([string_column]) - 2) + '%'  
        WHEN LEFT([string_column], 1) = '*' AND RIGHT([string_column], 1) <> '*' 
        THEN '%' + RIGHT([string_column], LEN([string_column]) - 1)
        WHEN LEFT([string_column], 1) <> '*' AND RIGHT([string_column], 1) = '*' 
        THEN LEFT([string_column], LEN([string_column]) - 1) + '%'
        ELSE [string_column] END AS [updated_string_column]
FROM [your_table_name];
```

### **[`Demo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/613744/replace-first-or-last-charecter-is-with-sql-server)**

Answer (score 4):

I'm just answering because the obvious to me is:

```
select '%' + substring(str, 2, len(str) - 2) + '%'
```

Of course, this would be a bit more complicated if you want to conditionally replace the characters when they are `'*'`.

Comment: I've been reading your answers for a while now Gordon and I think you always answer because "the answer is obvious to you".   :D

Answer (score 0):

Use `STUFF`,`LEFT` and `LEN` string functions

```
Declare @string varchar(50) = '*rg*niza*io*'

select stuff(left(@string,len(@string)-1),1,1,'%')+'%'
```

**Result :** `%rg*niza*io%`

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of the `CONCAT`, `LEFT`, `SUBSTRING` & `LEFT` functions.

```
SELECT CONCAT('%',LEFT(SUBSTRING(yourfield,2,LEN(yourfield)),LEN(yourfield)-2),'%')
FROM yourtable
```

Output: `%rg*niza*io%`